# I want to give team in GitHub Admin, Write, or Read access to any Team

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am not talking about: "You can give a team Admin, Write, or Read access to any repository." I want to give team Admin, Write, or Read access to any Team.

So I want to do the following:
I have 3 teams in our organization: Team1, Team1-1, Team1-2
Grant permissions to Team1 to Edit Permissions of Team1-1 
Grant permissions to Team1-1 to Edit Permissions of Team1-2

It does not seem like github has such permissiosn on the team level.
is there a way? even api solution or  alternatives?

Thanks
Luc

Answer (score 0):

At this time GitHub's permissions do not work the way you have described.

Are you working on GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise?  If you are on an Enterprise account, where you can create an unlimited amount of organizations, you could make the Team1 members organization owners of an organization dedicated to the projects Team1-1 works on. Then Team1-1 members can be organization owners over an organization that is specific to Team1-2 projects.  This would ensure Team1 can manage Team1-1 repository permissions, and Team 1-1 can manage Team 1-2's permissions. You could also execute this setup on GitHub.com, but you would incur charges per organization.